# GdkPixbuf change opacity

Tags: c, linux, gtk

Is it somehow possible to set the opacity of a of a `GdkPixbuf` to about 50%? The thing is i am writing in Gtk2 (cannot switch to Gtk3!) a filebrowser widget (for a remote file transfer) and I want the icons of the files to be 50% transparent if the file is hidden.

I get the icon using `GFileInfo` and load it into a `GdkPixbuf`, but I do not know how to change the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency is handled in the alpha channel. If your pixbuf isn't transparent (check with [gdk_pixbuf_get_has_alpha](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-has-alpha)), you may try to call [gdk_pixbuf_add_alpha](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Utilities.html#gdk-pixbuf-add-alpha) to add the alpha channel. Then you iterate on the pixels and set the alpha value for each pixel to 50% (i.e. 128) as gdk-pixbuf uses [unpremultiplied alpha](https://people.gnome.org/~federico/blog/my-gdk-pixbuf-braindump.html). See the documentation for a way to [iterate on the pixels](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.description).